# How to declare an Inno Setup preprocessor variable by reading from a file

Tags: inno-setup

Ok I know you can do this in Inno Setup:

```
#define AppVer "0.0.11"
```

Then use it like

```
[Setup]
AppVerName={#AppVer}
```

Now imagine I have a file named `VERSION` whose contents are "0.0.11".

Is there a way the contents of the file `VERSION` into the Inno Setup preprocessor variable somehow?

Comment: Can you confirm you want to read fromt he file at compile time? There is soem speculation in the answers with varying answers.

Comment: Yeah the file at compile time...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using ISPP's `GetFileVersion` function is the preferred method (since your installer version should match your application's version, after all).  So if this is what you actually wanted to do, you should accept jachguate's answer.

In case you really do want to read the version from a text file instead of from the executable file, then there are two possibilities:

The first: If you can modify the internal format of the file, then you can simplify things considerably by making it look like an INI file:

```
[Version]
Ver=0.0.11
```

Given this, you can use ISPP's `ReadIni` function to retrieve the version:

```
#define AppVer ReadIni("ver.ini", "Version", "Ver", "unknown")
```

The second alternative, if you can't change the file format, is to use the `FileOpen`, `FileRead`, and `FileClose` ISPP functions, eg:

```
#define VerFile FileOpen("ver.txt")
#define AppVer FileRead(VerFile)
#expr FileClose(VerFile)
#undef VerFile
```

I repeat, though: it's better to get the app version from the executable file itself instead.  This helps to ensure that everything matches up, for one thing.

Comment: Easier might be to have a file like `[Setup] AppVerName=0.0.11` and simply `#include` such file to the final script.

Comment: True, again only if the OP can customise the file format.  (Though don't use AppVerName, use AppVersion.)

Comment: Thanks for the ISPP functions! In case of using MS Access there is no such information in the .accdb/.accde file, so the functions are the only way I suppose.

Comment: The last example can also be inlined to `#define AppVer() Local[0] = FileOpen("ver.txt"), Local[1] = FileRead(Local[0]), FileClose(Local[0]), Local[1]`

Comment: Also note that for `ReadIni`, relative paths do not work, See [Inno Setup preprocessor can read a file using FileOpen, but not using ReadIni](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58231660/850848).

Answer (score 12):

You can use the Inno Setup Pre Proccessor (ISPP) `GetFileVersion` function to get the version directly from your executable file, like this:

```
[Setup]
#define AppVersion GetFileVersion("MyFile.exe")
#define AppName "My App name"

AppName={#AppName}
AppVerName={#AppName} {#AppVersion}
VersionInfoVersion={#AppVersion}

; etc
```

If you're using defines, you're already using ISPP.

Comment: +1. Good catch (presuming that the question is about at compile time rather than runtime, that is). :-)

Comment: @Ken Typically you get the version from a file known at compile time, so don't need to do that at run-time, which may involve extracting files from the installer to the target machine just to show the version.

Comment: That's why I gave you the upvote. :-) The question didn't specify, and I didn't catch the use of `#define` or interpret that possibility.

Answer (score 8):

In the event you want to do this at the installer's run time (@jachguate's answer covers the other possibility, and is probably the one you're looking for - I'll leave this in case it helps others at some point), you can use it's Pascal Script to do so. Something like this should work:

```
[Setup]
AppVer={code:MyVersion}

[Files]
// Other files
Source: "YourVersionFile.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Code]
function MyVersion(Param: String): String;
var
  VersionValue: string;
  VersionFile: string;
begin
  // Default to some predefined value.
  Result := '0.0.0';
  VersionFile := '{app}\YourVersionFile.txt';
  if LoadStringFromFile(VersionFile, VersionValue) then
    Result := VersionValue;
end;
```

See the help file topic "Pascal Scripting" for more information, including a list of the supported built-in functions.

Comment: You'll need an extra `ExpandConstant` in there (and depending on when the version is required, possibly an `ExtractTemporaryFile` too).  But I highly doubt that they'd want to read the version at install time anyway.

Comment: For some reason I've got the same logic and I can't seem to get it working because I'm using the `{#SetupSetting("AppVer")}` elsewhere, I have found @Miral seems to be the only one that functions correctly.

Comment: I would guess this has to do with compile-time verses run-time and the `{code:functionName}` is treated as a run-time value? Can someone comment on this?

Comment: @bnns I already did.  Code functions run at install time (and this particular code is incomplete because it's missing an `ExpandConstant` call).  `{#SetupSetting("AppVer")}` would just copy the literal code constant, to be expanded at runtime.  If the file doesn't exist at install time (and due to the missing `ExpandConstant`, it never exists), this will just return `0.0.0` always.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/

A C-like #include directive is supported, which pulls in lines from a separate file into the script at the position of the #include directive. The syntax is:

```
#include "filename.txt"
```

If the filename is not fully qualified, the compiler will look for it in the same directory as the file containing the `#include` directive. The filename may be prefixed by `compiler:`, in which case it looks for the file in the Compiler directory.