# In Inno Setup how to set a Global variable value dynamically

Tags: inno-setup

In my requirement, I need to set the value for the Global variables dynamically during run time. I need to read the name of the product which is stored in a text file and set it to the Global variables `MyAppName` and `MyAppVerName`  during run time. For eg: If the text file has the value as *Innovation*, and my global variables will be as mentioned below in the `iss` file:

```
#define MyAppName "ABC ProductName Database"
#define MyAppVerName "ABC ProductName Database 1.0.0"
```

Here the *ProductName* must be replaced by *Innovation*. The reading of text from the file and getting the value part is clear for me. But how to handle this and set the value dynamically for the global variables mentioned?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: See [How to declare an Inno Setup preprocessor variable by reading from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14530504/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, You are a lifesaver. The ver.txt solution worked perfectly fine for me. The ver.ini file solution was still not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: This works `#define VerFile FileOpen("common\Global_Config.txt")
#define AppVer FileRead(VerFile)
#expr FileClose(VerFile)
#undef VerFile` and this fails `#define AppVer ReadIni("common\GlobalConfig.ini", "Productname", "Product")`. This is the ini file content `[Productname]
Product=Innovation`

Comment: Please post a new question for your new problem.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl done!. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58231660/inno-setup-preprocessor-reading-a-value-from-txt-file-works-fine-but-ini-file

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in my script.

```
[Setup]
AppName=ABC {#ProductName} Database
```

then when executing via cmd,

```
iscc "/dProductName=Innovation" "c:\example\script.iss"
```

Comment: The objective is to use this setup dynamically for a couple of products so I have to read the value from a config file (.txt) and set it dynamically. So executing via cmd will work, but not a solution for my requirement.

Comment: @DeeJay007 you can read the text file using gradle and then use gradle to call inno via cmd.