# Inno Setup preprocessor can read a file using FileOpen, but not using ReadIni

Tags: inno-setup, ini

This is a clarification required to the existing post mentioned below
[How to declare an Inno Setup preprocessor variable by reading from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530504/how-to-declare-an-inno-setup-preprocessor-variable-by-reading-from-a-file)

Reading value from `.txt` file using `FileOpen` works perfectly fine, while reading `.ini` file using `ReadIni` returns an empty string.

The code for reading from txt file is:

```
#define VerFile FileOpen("common\GlobalConfig.txt")
#define AppVer FileRead(VerFile)
#expr FileClose(VerFile)
#undef VerFile
```

The txt file has the string *Innovation*.

The code for reading from ini file is:

```
#define AppVer ReadIni("common\GlobalConfig.ini", "Productname", "Product")
```

The content of the ini file is:

```
[Productname]
Product=Innovation
```

Both the files are in the same folder location.

The file is encoded with UTF-8 without BOM. I've checked with other types of encoding too, but it is returning only empty. I created with Notepad++.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative paths in `ReadIni` are resolved to the current working directory, what particularly in Inno Setup IDE is not the script directory.

Use absolute paths by using `SourcePath` [predefined variable](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=predefinedvars):

```
#define AppVer ReadIni( \
    SourcePath + "\common\GlobalConfig.ini", "Productname", "Product")
```

For `FileOpen` ISPP does that automatically, but not for `ReadIni`.

---

While not your case, another possibility is that there's something wrong with the INI file. It has to be UTF-8/ASCII without BOM or UTF-16 LE (with or without BOM).

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing. Thanks a ton Martin.